# multilevel caching with Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

I've searched about this question in many places, but haven't found answer.
According to rails guides and similar materials about caching, rails can use one of such cache types: in-memory, file storage, memcached, custom cache classes, and so on.

But  what if I want to use two or three cache types in one application, depending on cached entity?

For example (a high-load news agregator): I have a couple of front-end rails servers, couple of servers with sharded MongoDB and one server for memcached. What if I want to make

1. per-node in-memory cache on front-ends for very often used tiny collections (to avoid network latency acquiring data from memcached) for news sections and support data
2. memcached for most read latest news
3. file storage cache (can be stored in one network file storage mounted for all front-ends) for archive news (must be cached to avoid frequent mark-up processing, but is too big to store it in memory)

Answer (score 2):

**AFAIK** there's no cache plugin  or mechanism that enables the fine customization you desire. You can always write your own cache store that delegates to another subsystems according to what's being cached.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing. 'level2' may be what you're looking for. Repo: https://github.com/mezis/level2 Rubygems entry: https://rubygems.org/gems/level2/versions/0.2.5 A huge problem is that it doesn't work with dalli, the normal way to interact with memcached: https://github.com/mezis/level2/issues/6

I also found layercake but that appears abandoned: https://github.com/phaza/layercake

I really wish Rails had such a thing, it seems like a common desire.

I'm thinking about writing something like this myself, or at least creating a separate helper for a local memory cache & then using the "normal" Rails cache system for "normal" cache calls, as part of resolving this issue: https://github.com/coreinfrastructure/best-practices-badge/issues/1481